# Java pad address to 64-bit

Tags: java, string, formatting

I'm currently dealing with some memory addresses that I need to pad to a full 64-bit in length.  As an example:

```
0x7ffe0 - needs to be padded to: 0x000000007ffe0000
```

Essentially each value needs to be padding out to 16 digits with the zeros in the right places.

I know `String.format` will probably do it, but I'm not sure if `DecimalFormat` is quicker, or the better way to do this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

This is how the memory information is stored within the file:

[image]

Essentially the first 8 bytes are the start of a range, and the last 8 are where the range ends.

Another program I have access to is showing me the full 64-bit padded address, so I'm not entirely sure how it is performing the padding.

Comment: In what format do you have the addresses to start with?  Also, how would you tell the difference between 0x000000007ffe0000 and 0x000000000007ffe0? I'd interpret the number you have as the latter, so I'm not really sure how you got the former.

Comment: To be clear, you're asking how to format a `long` into your "full 64-bit" string format, right ? I don't see how you would use DecimalFormat for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
String s = String.format("0x%016x", 0x7ffe0);
```

DecimalFormat works only with decimals not hexadecimals

Comment: Thanks Evgeniy.  String.format("0x%016x", 0x7ffe0) produces 0x000000000007ffe0.  There are 11 zeros at the start, when there should only be 8.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that the issue here is that your hex numbers are in a nonstandard format. It is generally assumed that there are no hidden zeros to the right, and so if you want that result, you would have to start with 0x7ffe0000 instead of 0x7ffe0.

Comment: Ahh OK thanks. I'll take another look at how they are stored.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this

```
    System.out.printf("0x%016x", 0x7ffe0);
```